# Bootstrap 3 Aligning floated columns to the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying an info block with 3 rows in bootstrap. I'm using bootstrap cols to make these responsive. For smaller screns I'm using col-sm-4 and for larger screens I'm using col-lg-3, to make my images fit.

```
   <div class="container clearfix row" style="
width: 100%;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;">
        <!-- post list -->
        <div class="test col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="
                display: table-cell;
                margin: 0 auto;">
          <figure>
            <img alt="" src="assets/icons/find-awesome-stories.png">
            <figcaption>
              <span>
                test3
              </span>
            </figcaption>
            <!-- / post item wide -->
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="test col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style=" display: table-cell;        margin: 0 auto;">
          <figure>
            <img alt="" src="assets/icons/make-them-yours.png">
            <figcaption>
              <span>
                test 1
              </span>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="test col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="
display: table-cell;
margin: 0 auto;">
          <figure>
            <img alt="" src="assets/icons/show-it-off.png">
            <figcaption>
              test2
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

Now, my challenge is that I'm not able to center these elements. I've tried using `margin: 0 auto`, making them `table-table-cell`, and even tried the `inline-block` trick. But nothing seems to work. Can you please help me with this thanks.

Here's the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WJ3U9/2/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `text-align: center;`?

I think the default align is left！

you may try it out!

Comment: Yes, but my container has images as well. That won't help.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

change your :

```
<div class="container clearfix row" style=" width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
```

to

```
<div class="container">
```

because your markup is incorrect in the first place.**Then**,

add this to your markup css..... ( *just checked it for wide screen, not small ones* )

```
.test {
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
figure > img {
    width:100%; /* make image fit inside div*/
    height:auto;
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ3U9/8/)

Comment: Ok. You got me wrong. I'm not trying to center my images inside the .test div. I'm trying to center these three cards inside the container. The issue is the total column size is col-lg-9 on large screens, and I need to center this inside.

Comment: not wrong... *horribly wrong* ....bad coffee always gives bad results...so you want `container` contents to be centered even if you use `col-lg-3` on `12-grid` layout...right???

Comment: @skmvasu : changed the whole answer...please respond after checking!!